# How to use cql queries to get different datatypes out of cassandra with java client hector

Tags: cassandra, hector, cql

I'm new to cassandra and hector so i'm trying to execute cql queries but the problem is that not all columns are of type string so how dow I execute the query "select * from users"?

My column family looks like this:

```
UPDATE COLUMN FAMILY users
WITH comparator = UTF8Type
AND key_validation_class=UTF8Type
AND column_metadata = [
{column_name: full_name, validation_class: UTF8Type}
{column_name: email, validation_class: UTF8Type}
{column_name: state, validation_class: UTF8Type, index_type: KEYS}
{column_name: gender, validation_class: UTF8Type}
{column_name: birth_year, validation_class: LongType, index_type: KEYS}
{column_name: education, validation_class: UTF8Type}
];
```

I use the following code to execute the query:

```
CqlQuery<String, String, String> cqlQuery = new CqlQuery<String, String, String>(Keyspace,stringSerializer,stringSerializer,stringSerializer);

    cqlQuery.setQuery("select * from users");

    QueryResult<CqlRows<String, String, String>> result = cqlQuery.execute();


    if (result != null && result.get() != null) {
        List<Row<String, String, String>> list = result.get().getList();
        for (Row row : list) {
            System.out.println(".");
            List columns = row.getColumnSlice().getColumns();
            for (Iterator iterator = columns.iterator(); iterator.hasNext();) {
                HColumn column = (HColumn) iterator.next();
                System.out.print(column.getName() + ":" + column.getValue()
                        + "\t");
            }
            System.out.println("");
        }
    }
```

But because of the 'birth_year' column with validation class Long I can't get the value.
I get the following result assuming that there is only one record:

```
KEY:Carl birth_year: 'strange chars?' full_name:Carl Smith gender:M eduction:electrician state:LA
```

If I change my query to this:

```
CqlQuery<String, String, Long> cqlQuery =  new CqlQuery<String, String, Long>
TutorialBase.tutorialKeyspace, stringSerializer, stringSerializer, longSerializer);

    cqlQuery.setQuery("select birth_year from users");
```

Than it works.

So how can I do this with only one query and what if I have more datatypes like booleans and floats in the rows of a column family?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You specify the value type as String in the CqlRows, so every value is expected to be a string. Because you want to mix Value types, you should keep the column metadata, but also specify the default validation class as *BytesType* in the schema and then use ByteBuffer as the type in CqlRows:

```
QueryResult<CqlRows<String, String, ByteBuffer>> result = cqlQuery.execute();
```

Then, when processing the values, you will have to convert to the appropriate type, and instead of iterating through the columns, you will probably get the specific column by name:

```
ColumnSlice<String, ByteBuffer> slice = row.getColumnSlice();
HColumn<String,ByteBuffer> col = slice.getColumnByName("birth_year");
System.out.println(" birth_year: " + col.getValue().getLong());
```

Of course, Strings have to be handled differently, using java.nio.charset.Charset:

```
Charset.defaultCharset().decode(col.getValue()).toString()
```

You can determine types from the Column meta-data, but I've only done this via the Thrift API (see ColumnDef), so not sure how to do it via Hector API. But HColumn does provide a getValueSerializer() method, so that could be a start.

Comment: Hi libjack, thanks for your reaction.

Do you mean that it is only possible if all the columns in a column family have byteBuffer as the default validation class? That's not exectly what I want, because when inserting data into cassandra the check of valid data is not working. It would be possible to insert a string in the column birth_year.

I am trying your code, but the method 'getLong()' is not recognized.

Comment: I found what was wrong whith: "col.getValue().getLong()"
It should be "column.getValueBytes().getLong()"
My previous question is solved. It is possible to have multiple validation_classe in a column family.

Comment: Right, getLong() is a method on ByteBuffer, so getValue() will only return a ByteBuffer if that is the type specified for HColumn:

Comment: He libjack, I'm trying to determine types from the column meta-data with ColumnDef. But do I need to ask for the columns trough the Trift api? And if yes how do I do that? You said that You've done this, do you have an example?

Comment: The Cluster#describeKeyspace method will return a KeyspaceDefinition with the Keyspace, ColumnFamily and metadata hierarchy fully populated.

Comment: You can also replace Charset.defaultCharset().decode(col.getValue()).toString() with ByteBufferUtil.string(col.getValue()) (as of Hector 1.0-2)