# CQL2 Java Client Results Binary Data

Tags: cassandra, cql

I have built a table using CQL2, data looks fine from cqlsh as well as hive command prompt. But when I am reading the data from java client it shows up binary value for 2 columns, as shown below

```
"hr1":"\u0000\u0000\u0000\u000e","hr2":"\u0000\u0000\u0000)"
```

After creating table have created index on column "col1" from CQL prompt.

My java code looks like :

```
   public void read() {
        if (null != cluster && null != keySpace) {
            CqlQuery<String, String, String> cqlQuery = new CqlQuery<String, String, String>(
                    keySpace, StringSerializer.get(), StringSerializer.get(),
                    StringSerializer.get());
            cqlQuery.setQuery("select * from myTable where col1 = 'HR100'");
            QueryResult<CqlRows<String, String, String>> result = cqlQuery
                    .execute();
            CqlRows rows = result.get();
            for (int i = 0; i < rows.getCount(); i++) {
                RowImpl<String, String, String> row = (RowImpl<String, String, String>) rows
                        .getList().get(i);
                System.out.println("Row key = " + row.getKey());
                for (HColumn<String, String> column : row.getColumnSlice()
                        .getColumns()) {
                    System.out.println("Column name = "
                            + column.getName().toString());
                    System.out.println("Colmn value = "
                            + column.getValue().toString());
                }
            }

        }
    }
```

Comment: Can you post your schema?

Comment: Following is schema definition -                                          CREATE TABLE myTable (
  col1 varchar PRIMARY KEY,
  col2  varchar,
  col3 varchar,
  hr1 int,
  hr2 int,
  hr3 varchar
);

Comment: I am providing schema as part of 4-5 comments as post doesn't allow me.     ColumnFamily: myTable 
    Key Validation Class: org.apache.cassandra.db.marshal.UTF8Type
      Default column value validator: org.apache.cassandra.db.marshal.UTF8Type
      Cells sorted by: org.apache.cassandra.db.marshal.UTF8Type
      GC grace seconds: 864000
      Compaction min/max thresholds: 4/32
      Read repair chance: 0.1
      DC Local Read repair chance: 0.0
      Populate IO Cache on flush: false
      Replicate on write: true
      Caching: KEYS_ONLY
      Bloom Filter FP chance: default

Comment: Built indexes: [myTable.col3, myTable.hr1, myTable.hr2]
      Column Metadata:
        Column Name: col2
          Validation Class: org.apache.cassandra.db.marshal.UTF8Type
        Column Name: hr2
          Validation Class: org.apache.cassandra.db.marshal.Int32Type
        Column Name: hr1
          Validation Class: org.apache.cassandra.db.marshal.Int32Type
          Index Name: ahr
          Index Type: KEYS
          Index Options: {}

Comment: Column Name: col3
          Validation Class: org.apache.cassandra.db.marshal.UTF8Type
          Index Name: adt
          Index Type: KEYS
          Index Options: {}
        Column Name: col1
          Validation Class: org.apache.cassandra.db.marshal.UTF8Type
          Index Name: snm
          Index Type: KEYS
          Index Options: {}
      Compaction Strategy: org.apache.cassandra.db.compaction.SizeTieredCompactionStrategy      Compression Options:
        sstable_compression: org.apache.cassandra.io.compress.SnappyCompressor

Comment: @BryceAtNetwork23 do you need any further information, please let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here the problem is you are trying to read every value as Strings. That approach works for string values. But when it comes to other types, you must have to specify the appropriate Serialiser before reading. You can use column metadata to know the data types for a columnfamily.

So iteration is impossible in such situation and you must have to read individual columns as follows.

```
ColumnSlice<String, Integer> slice = row.getColumnSlice();
HColumn<String,Integer> col = slice.getColumnByName("column_name");
```

Here I have used an Integer type as value since I'm expecting an integer.

Please find more details in [How to use cql queries to get different datatypes out of cassandra with java client hector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7732651/how-to-use-cql-queries-to-get-different-datatypes-out-of-cassandra-with-java-cli)